# Codeigniter : Change password for logged in user and for password that uses md5

Tags: php, codeigniter, passwords, md5

I want to ask how to change password for logged in user,
I can change the password when I enter password that matches anyone in database.
For just example, user have "admin" password, I just enter the current password,
new password and confirm password.

Current password: admin
New Password: newadmin
Current Password: new admin

And also  I don't know how to change the password if the password
uses md5(). I hope you can help me, I am a newbie on Codeigniter.
I  search answers but I really don't understand it so I want to comment but 
it's required 50 reputation so I post new question.

Here's my code :

**Controller**

```
    public function update(){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Current Password', 'required|alpha_numeric|min_length[6]|max_length[20]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('newpass', 'New Password', 'required|alpha_numeric|min_length[6]|max_length[20]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('confpassword', 'Confirm Password', 'required|alpha_numeric|min_length[6]|max_length[20]');

    if($this->form_validation->run()){
        $cur_password = $this->input->post('password');
        $new_password = $this->input->post('newpass');
        $conf_password = $this->input->post('confpassword');
        $this->load->model('queries');
        $userid = '1';
        $passwd = $this->queries->getCurrPassword($userid);
        if($passwd->password == $cur_password){
            if($new_password == $conf_password){
                if($this->queries->updatePassword($new_password, $userid)){
                    echo 'Password updated successfully';
                }
                else{
                    echo 'Failed to update password';
                }
            }
            else{
                echo 'New password & Confirm password is not matching';
            }
        }
        else{
            echo'Sorry! Current password is not matching';

    }
}
else{
    echo validation_errors();
}
```

**model**

```
 public function getCurrPassword($userid){
  $query = $this->db->where(['id'=>$userid])
                    ->get('users');
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return $query->row();
    } }

  public function updatePassword($new_password, $userid){
  $data = array(
      'password'=> $new_password
      );
      return $this->db->where('id', $userid)
                      ->update('users', $data); }
```

Comment: are your password data stored as md5 in your db ?

Comment: @sintakonte Yes, it is.

Comment: With PHP use `password_hash` and `password_verify`. Discussion: When saving a password verifier just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as PBKDF2, Rfc2898DeriveBytes, password_hash, Bcrypt, passlib.hash or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a substantial of time finding passwords by brute force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution for my problem.

**For logged in user** I just changed the $userid = '1'; into
$userid = $this->session->userdata('account_id');

**And for the md5 password**
I just add md5 on passwords.Like what @sintakonte did and @zaph is right.

"Only use strong password hashing algorithms like BCrypt, which is used in PHP’s own Password Hashing functions."

Reference : https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/security.html

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

If it is about an application whose Admin password you don't remember, then please try this [solution](https://superuser.com/questions/1659347/how-to-change-user-password-in-phpmyadmin/1756207#1756207)

Not yet marked but I don't see any other way, been at this for weeks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not going to discuss the md5 subject here, but you should avoid those weak algorithms because they aren't safe. Use `password_verify` and `password_hash` for this purpose. (but as i said i'm not a missionary)

you need to organize your code a bit better - because this is a mess ;)

try the following - **your controller**

```
public function update()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Current Password', 'required|alpha_numeric|min_length[6]|max_length[20]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('newpass', 'New Password', 'required|alpha_numeric|min_length[6]|max_length[20]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('confpassword', 'Confirm Password', 'required|alpha_numeric|min_length[6]|max_length[20]');

    if($this->form_validation->run())
    {
        $cur_password = $this->input->post('password');
        $new_password = $this->input->post('newpass');
        $conf_password = $this->input->post('confpassword');
        $this->load->model('queries');
        $userid = '1';

        try
        {
            $objUser = $this->queries->getUser($userid);
            if ($objUser->password != md5($cur_password))   throw new Exception('Sorry! Current password is not matching');
            if ($new_password != $conf_password)    throw new Exception('New password & Confirm password is not matching');
            $this->queries->updatePassword($new_password, $userid);
            echo 'Password updated successfully';

        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo validation_errors();
    }
}
```

and your **model**

```
public function getUser($userid)
{
    $query = $this->db->where(id,$userid])->get('users');
    if($query->num_rows() == 1)
    {
        return $query->row();
    }
    throw new Exception("no user data found");
}

 public function updatePassword($new_password, $userid)
 {
    $data = array
    (
        'password'=> md5($new_password)
    );
    if (!$this->db->where('id', $userid)->update('users', $data))
    {
        throw new Exception('Failed to update password');
    }
}
```

there is no need to name your model function `getCurrPassword` if it is in fact returning an user object - so i renamed that.

Comment: Do not help developer provide poor security that puts the users at risk. Would you also not be a missionary and help someone jump off a bridge? Or in this case help provide bad to non-existent security to potentially thousands of users? Sure, this is a moral issue, prioritize the developer or all of the users. Note: This answer may well be consulted by hundreds of future developers.

Comment: @sintakonte i tried the codes you provided but it always display "no user data found" and it's change the password of the logged_in user

Comment: @zaph - i didn't provide anything - in fact i said this is a weak approach and shouldn't be used at all - but i'm not interested here to discuss this because the topic here was a total different one... (and your jumping off the bridge example - if you know death isn't a loss at all - but the jumper doesn't, and want to take the risk to experience it - i guess i wouldn't interfere...)

Comment: @squaredsquared then i guess you don't have a user with that id in your database

Comment: I got my solution below. Anyway, thanks for the help. @sintakonte